# Regex in D capturing too much

Tags: regex, d

I'm writing a function which is designed to take a text like this:

```
%%HEADER
foo bar baz
%%BODY
foo baz baz
```

And return an array like this:

```
{"foo bar baz", "foo baz baz"}
```

With that in mind, I wrote the following:

```
string[2] separate_header_body(string input) {
  string[2] separated;
  auto header = matchFirst(input, regex(r"%%HEADER\n((.|\n)*)\n%%BODY", "g"));
  if (header.empty()) {
    throw new ParserException("No %%HEADER found.");
  } else {
    separated[0] = header.front();
    auto bdy = matchFirst(input, regex(r"%%BODY\n((.|\n)*)", "g"));
    if (bdy.empty()) {
      throw new ParserException("No %%BODY found.");
    } else {
      separated[1] = bdy.front();
    }
  }
  return separated;
}
```

However, when I try to test it with the following input:

```
"%%HEADER\nfoo bar baz\n%%BODY\nfoo baz baz"
```

The first capture is `"%%HEADER\nfoo bar baz\n%%BODY`, which is clearly too much. Am I using `std.regex` incorrectly for what I want?

Comment: you need to match the second generally when you use REGEX the first capture group the entire capture, `index 1` is your actual first capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first element (`front`) of a capture group is the full match, from the first character of your pattern to the last. After that comes the first submatch, i.e. the first parenthesized section.

So, use `[1]` instead of `front`. Or `popFront` the full match away so that `front` is the first submatch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
auto m = matchFirst(input, regex(r"%%HEADER\n(.*?)\n%%BODY", "s"));
string header = m.captures[1];
```

and

```
auto m = matchFirst(input, regex(r"%%BODY\n(.*)", "s"));
string body = m.captures[1];
```

the s modifier allows the dot to match the newline character.

The question mark `?` makes the `*` quantifier lazy. Then it stops at the first occurence of `"\n%%BODY"`

Note that it is possible to extract the two fields in one shot with a pattern like this:

```
auto m = matchFirst(regex(r"%%HEADER\n(.*?)\n%%BODY\n(.*)", "s"));

string header = m.captures[1];
string body = m.captures[2];

if (header.empty()) {
    throw new ParserException("No %%HEADER found.");
} else {
    separated[0] = header;
}

if (body.empty()) {
    throw new ParserException("No %%BODY found.");
} else {
    separated[1] = body;
}
```

You only need to extract the two capturing groups.

Comment: Well explained, +1 :)

Comment: @zx81: Thanks, it was my first try with this unknown (for me) language.

Comment: Congrats, then... And it looks like you have [another chance to practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24967276/1078583). :)