# Return value of std.regex.regex?

Tags: regex, d, phobos

I'm trying to write a function that takes an input string, a regex (made by `std.regex.regex` from a rawstring) and an error message string, and attempt to match something from the input string using the regex, displaying the error message if there are no matches. I came up with the following signature so far:

```
string check_for_match (string input, Regex r, string error_message)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, as the compiler complains, saying:

```
struct std.regex.Regex(Char) is used as a type
```

So what should I use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll compile if you change `Regex` to `Regex!char`.

The reason is that `Regex` is a template that can use any character size: `char` for UTF-8 patterns, `wchar` for UTF-16, or `dchar` for UTF-32. The compiler is saying you need to create a type by passing the required `Char` argument there to use it here.

Since you are working with `string`, which is made up of `char`s, `Regex!char` is the type to use.

```
string check_for_match (string input, Regex!char r, string error_message) { return null; }
```